# Combine 2 ArrayAdapter

Tags: android

i want to make a Real Time Trading App.. but i have a problem to combine 2 adapter into one adapter. so i need help from you all :D

here's my code

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_item);

    final uraikonversiActivity cp = new uraikonversiActivity(this);
    final ListView list = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.list);
    final String list_array[] = new String[cp.kodekonversi.size()];
    final Float list_nilai[] = new Float[cp.nilaikonversi.size()];


    for (int i = 0; i < cp.kodekonversi.size(); i++) {
        list_array[i] = cp.kodekonversi.get(i);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < cp.nilaikonversi.size(); i++) {
        list_nilai[i] = cp.nilaikonversi.get(i);

    }



    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list_array);
    ArrayAdapter adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list_nilai);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

}}
```

(note : this a real time so i got the arraylist from the internet)

my goal is to show something like this at the list = "USD   -   1.xxxxx".

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At last  you are displaying all data withing one listview.So just convert both arrays into one like this(as both arrays are of same lenth):

```
String[] finalArray = new String[list_array.length + list_nilai.length];
for(int i = 0; i< cp.nilaikonversi.size(); ++i)
finalArray[i] = list_array[i] +"-" + list_nilai[i];

ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, finalArray);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Hope it will help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Build up your own adapter, do not just rely on `ArrayAdapter`.
When building an adapter there is the method `public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` in wich you can code how every single line should look like. Just return a layout containing two textfields wich are filled by your `list_array` and `list_nilai`.

See also: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html 
or for a complete tutorial: http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=327